# iPad segue error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, segue, master-detail

Noob Xcode question here.

I have a basic Master-Detail setup.

When I choose an item in the master list, it brings a second "master" sidebar with the details, instead of updating the details page.

So I start with this:
[image]

I click on "Nick Jones" and get this:
[image]

The storyboard looks like this:
[image]

But if I click on the Master View Controller, the Detail View Controller changes size to this:
[image]

I'm trying to adapt the tutorial "Your Second iOS App" tutorial to iPad (rather than iPhone). The key segue page is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html). I've reestablished a segue link between the navigation controller and the Detail View Controller because it doesn't work hardly at all without it, but I'm clearly doing it wrongly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. The obvious problem is the type of segue you have from the master view controller to the detail view controller. It should be a "replace" segue, and when you select that segue and click on the attributes inspector, make sure you specify the destination of the "detail split":

   [image: detail split]
2. As an aside, the reason that the storyboard is a little confused on the UI, is that you've got two segues into that detail view controller, one from the details view of the split view controller (and thus the squarish shape of the details scene), and another from the master view controller (and thus the, incorrect, narrow shape of the details scene). The poor Interface Builder is probably sitting there thinking "hey, did you want me to use this scene as the details for a split view, or as a replacement for the master view controller?!?" My previous point resolves this conflict, but this explains why, in your current storyboard, the shape of the details scene changes based upon which scene you currently have selected.
3. If you're going to do it this way, I'd suggest that you might want the segue from the master scene to the details scene to actually go from the master to the navigation controller scene, not to the details scene itself:

   [image: go to navigation controller]
4. To be quite blunt, though, having described how to fix the segue, *you shouldn't be using a segue!* Create a blank new "master-detail" project and see what it does. You'll notice that it looks more like:

   [image]

You really only want the segue from the master scene to the details scene if you're *changing* the details view controller to a different scene. But you're not doing that. You probably only want to tell the details view controller that the object it's looking at has changed and that it should `reloadData`. And given that your details view controller is a tableview, itself, the the master view controller would have a method that does something like (a) tell the detail view controller what detail item it's looking at; and (b) tell it to `reloadData`. So it might look something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;

    [self.detailViewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You can make it work either way, but I would have thought that this latter approach might make more sense.

Comment: Deep gratitude flowing your way from Down Under right now. I can't implement your advice at this point (or my wife will be grievously displeased), but +1 and tick in blind faith that I can cobble something together from your most comprehensive answer. Good on you :)

Comment: Still having grief, I'm afraid :(  I've adopted your no segue approach, but it's not passing the data. The custom method is `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Student *studentAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.student = studentAtIndex;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}`. I know studentAtIndex is pointing to the right place, because if I put in `studentAtIndex.firstName = @"Ben"`, it changes the master. Can you see an error? Should I post another question? Thanks.

Comment: @Nick I'd suggest double checking the values of `self.detailViewController` and of `self.detailViewController.tableView` to make sure they're both not `nil`. I know I once spent a lot of time debugging a split view suffering from this before I noticed that `detailViewController` wasn't getting initialized (e.g. you need something in `viewDidLoad` that initializes it, like `self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];`. iOS doesn't really ever warn us if an object pointer is `nil`.

Comment: @Nick Just put breakpoints in your code, and [single step](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW27) through the relevant routines, and you'll find out where it's slipping through the cracks! I know it works, though, because I tested it here!

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Just for the record, I did get it working with the segue following your instructions, but the no-segue way (!) is definitely preferable. I'll try some stuff when I get home from work. All the best.

Comment: Success :)  I'd commented out where the pointer is established, and it was as you said: `self.detailViewController = (CRDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];` Thanks again.